# How to set auto height for extjs hbox layout?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

i have this layout and once im setting some data dynamically layout doesn't resize and final result is like this

[image: issue]

this is the code im using

```
win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
      title: 'Layout Window',
      closable: true,
      closeAction: 'hide',
      width: 750,
      height: 500,
      layout: 'fit',
      animCollapse: true,
      bodyPadding: 5,

      items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                items: [{
                          xtype: 'fieldset',
                          flex:1,
                          title: 'Details',
                          margins:'0 5 0 0',
                          layout: 'anchor',                          
                          autoHeight: true,
                          items: [{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                    name: 'customer_name',
                                    id: 'customer_name',
                                    width: 300
                                },{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'ID Card',
                                    id: 'customer_id',
                                    name: 'customer_id',
                                    width: 300
                                },{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Address',
                                    name: 'address',
                                    id: 'address',
                                    width: 300
                                }]                        
                      },{
                          xtype: 'fieldset',
                          title: 'Details',
                          margins:'0 0 5 0',
                          flex:1,
                          layout: 'anchor',
                          autoHeight: true,
                          items: [{
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    labelWidth: 120,
                                    fieldLabel: 'invoice',
                                    anchor: '98%',
                                    name: 'invoice_number',
                                    id: 'invoice_number',
                                    allowBlank: false,
                                    readOnly: true
                                },{
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    labelWidth: 120,
                                    fieldLabel: 'Payment Amount',
                                    anchor: '98%',
                                    name: 'payment_amount',
                                    id: 'payment_amount',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                },{
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    id: 'test'

                                    }]                        
                      }]                        
             }]


}).show();
```

this, i just used for setting data to display fields as test

```
Ext.getCmp('test').on('click', function(){
    Ext.getCmp('customer_name').setValue('customer name customer_name customer_name customer_name');
    Ext.getCmp('customer_id').setValue('855');
    Ext.getCmp('address').setValue('some text, some text, some text, some text');
});
```

any idea how to fix this ?

Regards

Comment: In fact it's one of the pain in ExtJS4. Interested to find out how to achieve that without listening to resize events.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, this is the quick hack that will make your fieldset on the left to auto expand by the length of the content:

Right after you set the content of the display fieldset, do this:

```
win.query('fieldset')[0].setHeight('auto');
```

Without much modification, this is the example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/kfZp5/)

*([`query`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query) is a method available global to all the components that inherit `Ext.Component`, to query the items underneath, like css selectors)*

**Extra Note**

A few things to note:

1. To use `align:'stretch'`, you can't provide it as a direct configuration to the component, you will need to do this:

   ```
   Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
       layout: {
           type: 'hbox',
           align: 'stretch'
       },
       items: [...]
   });
   ```

   You will want to [check out this testing demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/5e86T/). First window will work as expected, while second and third window fails to stretch the panels.
2. Secondly, `autoHeight` has been dropped since ExtJS 4 and so it's ignored in your configuration. You probably need to use the `setHeight('auto')` to make it autoHeight manually.

**EDIT**

Seems like using `column` layout can achieve same effect without using `setHeight('auto')`. [Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/TLRbf/).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot.   wonder which layout can be used to get exact same output with auto height support. tried column layout but couldn't get space between two fieldsets

Comment: If you need spaces you can set the `style` or even `bodyStyle` of the components to have some sort of css `margin` or `padding`.

Comment: seems like column layout doesn't allow that though.  anyway thanks for all of this.

Comment: @Gihan Why not? [Check out my example on `column` layout](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/TLRbf/). Note that I have removed the hack I mentioned earlier. Your fieldset expands automatically.

Comment: Thanks :)  oh ya damn i check for this whole night. i tried to use margins: '', seems like thats where i screwed

Comment: This is what I do usually. If `margins` can't work, use `style` or `bodyStyle`. That should work in most cases. `style` will apply style to the outermost of the wrapper div, while `bodyStyle` will apply style to the inner `body` el.